# Call a stored procedure, and return at once in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql, I need to call multiple stored procedures sequentially. Is this calling process sequential? That is to say, wait for the execution of each stored procedure to end before executing the next stored procedure? Or, is this an asynchronous call?

Postgres version used is 14.5.

Comment: How to call multiple stored procedures sequentially? One by one.

Comment: Can't you test this yourself to find out, faster than you can ask here?

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        call "wd_ft_31_C01_GZFLFY_01_YH"(usrYYYYMM, '01', usrXXBSM);
 call "wd_ft_31_C01_GZFLFY_02_YH"(usrYYYYMM, '02', usrXXBSM);
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       

        01 stored procedure creates a cte_one temp table on commit drop as. When execute all two procedures as above, there is a error "relation cte_one" exists.  If execut only one procedure sequentially, there is no error.

Comment: 02 stored procedure also create a cte_one temp table as 01 stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you execute SQL statement is a single database session, they are guaranteed to be executed synchronously and sequentially.